# Swipe Scroll with a datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scroll, datagridview, windows-7

Is there away to adjust the scroll position with a datagridview? I want to implement away for the user to scroll up and down or left and right with their finger instead of using the scroll bars for touch screen purposes. I know with certain controls you have a AutoScrollPosition built in but what can I use to change the scroll position to move with the finger using the datagridview on winforms? The OS is Windows 7 and the framework is 4. I want to make it when they start to do a panning motion to turn panning on and have them scroll.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing as you. All I can find are the Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling Offset but one is read only so you couldn't use them to go up and down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I accomplished what you are asking.

```
Private Sub DataGridView_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove
    Select Case e.Button
        Case MouseButtons.Left
            Dim mouseMovement As Point = GetMouseMovement(e.Location)
            If Panning Then
                If mouseMovement.X = 0 Then
                    Me.AutoScrollOffset = Point.Round(New PointF(-AutoScrollOffset.X, mouseMovement.Y - AutoScrollOffset.Y))
                ElseIf mouseMovement.Y = 0 Then
                    Me.AutoScrollOffset = Point.Round(New PointF((mouseMovement.X / Convert.ToSingle(Math.Abs(mouseMovement.X))) * 10 - AutoScrollOffset.X, -AutoScrollOffset.Y))
                Else
                    Me.AutoScrollOffset = Point.Round(New PointF((mouseMovement.X / Convert.ToSingle(Math.Abs(mouseMovement.X))) * 10 - AutoScrollOffset.X, mouseMovement.Y - AutoScrollOffset.Y))
                End If
                Me.ClearSelection()
            End If
    End Select
End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Checks if there is any mouse movement based on passed in point
''' </summary>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Private Function GetMouseMovement(ByVal point As Point) As Point
    If Math.Abs(mouseDownPosition.X - point.X) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Width Or
           Math.Abs(mouseDownPosition.Y - point.Y) >= SystemInformation.DoubleClickSize.Height Then
        _panning = True
        Return New Point(point.X - mouseDownPosition.X, point.Y - mouseDownPosition.Y)
    End If
    _panning = False
    Return New Point(0, 0)
End Function
```